# C# (and MongoDB) DateTime conversion (from BSON to C# object)

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

I've been using MongoDB C# driver, transferring some documents from our current database to MongoDB and the other way round. The problem I get is (in short): Although the method for retrieving DateTime from a MongoDB document returns the correct date/time, when assigned to a DateTime attribute of my C# object it reverts to 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM,  that is, to a min DateTime value.

More details:

GetdateTime is querying MongoDB (rdoc is a BSON document) and returning the correct date/time:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetDateTime(rdoc, "recordedDate"));
```

The output is:

6/3/2010 10:00:00 AM

I assign the returned value to my c# object:

```
doc.RecordedDate = GetDateTime(rdoc, "recordedDate");
```

but when I access this attribute using (r is my c# object):

```
Console.WriteLine(r.UserID + "," + r.DateCreated);
```

I get:
123456,1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

I am setting my DateTime field with:

```
set{ recordedDate = value.ToLocalTime();  }
```

Just to mention here that I am not actually updating our database when creating c# docs, just keeping these docs into memory then resaving them to Mongo (don't ask), just for testing purposes. It shouldn't affect the problem I am having, all other fields work fine.

I know that there is some missmatch between DateTime objects of BSON and .NET (BSON truncates number of Ticks or something) but don't if this is causing my problem...

Btw, I only started using c# three days ago, so if I am missing something basic and obvious here, please point it out gently :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a mismatch between how you're storing your data.

This is updating the property `doc.RecordedDate`:

```
doc.RecordedDate = GetDateTime(rdoc, "recordedDate");
```

But you are reading from the property `DateCreated`:

```
Console.WriteLine(r.UserID + "," + r.DateCreated)
```

And this is writing to a third variable 'recordedDate':

```
set{ recordedDate = value.ToLocalTime();  }
```

You're writing to a thing named RecordedDate, but reading from a thing named DateCreated. Where do you actually update DateCreated? What is the relationship between doc.RecordedDate and r.DateCreated? What is the relationship between recordedDate and doc.RecordedDate or r.DateCreated?

Comment: And that was it! (thanks for pointing it out)
The class of my r object inherits a class containing a DateCreated property, but that one was never set, so I was getting the min date value.